# Linear algebra - proof that two subspaces are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $W$, $U$ and $P$ , which are three subspaces of $V$.

If $U\cap W=P\cap W$, and $U+W=P+W$, we have to prove that $U=P$.

I know that if a vector is in the intersection of U and W, that vector has to be in both subespaces; I mean, if the vector is v, v is in W and v is in U. So we can write v as the combination of vectors of U; and also as the combination of the vectors of W. But my problem is that I don't know what more to do to gain information to prove the proposition.

Comment: Good; so, in addition to informing of what your assignment is, can you tell us what you've managed to do and why you are unable to complete the assignment?

Comment: i know that if a vector is in the intersection of U and W, that vector has to be in both subespaces; I mean, if the vector is v, v is in W and v is in U So we can write v as the combination of vectors of U; and also as the combination of the vectors of W. But my problem is that I don't know what more to do to gain information to prove the proposition.

Comment: Put it in the post, not buried in the comments. That is: provide context and evidence of effort. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: "If $v$ is in $U$, then we can write $v$ as a combination of vectors in $U$." Well, yes, $v=v$ is $v$ written as a linear combination of vectors in $U$.

Comment: Consider three distinct lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you can actually prove this statement. Hint: very surprised!

Comment: Which is the problem?

Comment: Did you consider the three distinct lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ yet? This was not a throwaway comment by Arturo Magidin.

Comment: If you understand that the proposition is true, even after considering three distinct lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then there is something fundamentally wrong with both your understanding and how you considered the three lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$W=\text{Span}\,\{(1,1)\}\;,\;\;P=\text{Span}\,\{(1,0)\}\;,\;\;U=\text{Span}\,\{(0,1)\}$$

Then

$$W\cap P=W\cap U=\{0\}\,,\,\,\text{and also}\;\;W+P=W+U=\Bbb R^2$$

yet $\;P\neq U\;$ . The claim is false.